# How to retrieve raw bytes of DNS response?

Tags: dns, packet

I want to retrieve raw bytes of DNS response for debugging reason, for example:

```
dig  -t https clickhouse.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
clickhouse.com.         242     IN      HTTPS   1 . alpn="h3,h3-29,h2" ipv4hint=172.66.40.249,172.66.43.7 ipv6hint=2606:4700:3108::ac42:28f9,2606:4700:3108::ac42:2b07
```

How can I get the bytes of those answer section, is there some existing tool that can show me those raw bytes before decoded into plain text?

I tried with wireshark but it's encrypted, tried with another dns server but I don't get any response (seems blocked by ISP).

**UPDATE**:

so I do manual way, create a simple program in Go:

```
    m := &dns.Msg{
        MsgHdr: dns.MsgHdr{
            Authoritative:     false,
            AuthenticatedData: false,
            CheckingDisabled:  true,
            RecursionDesired:  true,
            Opcode:            dns.OpcodeQuery,
        },
        Question: make([]dns.Question, 1),
    }
    q := &m.Question[0]
    q.Qclass = dns.ClassINET
    q.Qtype = dns.TypeHTTPS
    q.Name = "clickhouse.com."

    // 0 = {uint8} 0

    r, err := dns.Exchange(m, "9.9.9.9:9953")
```

put breakpoint on `dns.Answer, off, err = unpackRRslice(int(dh.Ancount), msg, off)` on `github.com/miekg/dns/msg.go:840` then copy paste the `msg` to text file.

Comment: How do you know it's encrypted? Your command doesn't have any of the options that would make dig use DNS-over-TLS. What do you see in Wireshark?

Comment: Are you interested in just the record data of the answer(s), or the whole answer section/response?

Comment: @user1686 i see everything encrypted, i don't see any "clickhouse" string at all on captured packets

Comment: @Torin since DNS allow part compression, I guess it should be whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of `dig` (9.11.0 or later), you can pass the `+unknownformat` flag:

> ```
> +[no]unknownformat
>     This option prints all RDATA in unknown RR type presentation format (RFC 3597).
>     The default is to print RDATA for known types in the type's presentation format.
> ```

As an example, querying `example.com. IN SOA` gives

```
$ dig +unknownformat example.com. soa
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.net.        3532    CLASS1  TYPE6   \# 53 026E73056963616E6E036F726700036E6F6303646E73056963616E6E 036F7267007886A9DA00001C2000000E100012750000000E10
...
```

This format ([RFC 3597](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3597)) presents the raw record data wire-format in the format `\# <rdata-length> <rdata>...` where `rdata` is hex encoded and may be split into multiple words, so the above is

```
00000000: 026e 7305 6963 616e 6e03 6f72 6700 036e  .ns.icann.org..n
00000010: 6f63 0364 6e73 0569 6361 6e6e 036f 7267  oc.dns.icann.org
00000020: 0078 86a9 da00 001c 2000 000e 1000 1275  .x...... ......u
00000030: 0000 000e 10                             .....
```